# How can I add a class to div when clicking on list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on the below list item element:

```
<li class="menu-item-473" id="wp_nav_menu-item-473"></li>
```

I want to add the class 'active' to the below element:

```
<div id="gldbm-panel" class="gldbm-panel">
```

Whilst keeping the original 'gldbm-panel' class so it appears like this.

```
<div id="gldbm-panel" class="gldbm-panel active">
```

Tried the below solutions to no avail. **Any ideas?**

My Unsuccessful Vanilla Solution:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var faqContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-473');
  var faqToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('gldbm-panel')[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < faqContainers.length; i++) {

    faqContainers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      if (faqToggle.classList.contains('active')) {
        faqToggle.classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        faqToggle.classList.add('active');
      }

    });
  }


});
```

My Unsuccessful JQuery Solution(s):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','#menu-item-473',function(){
      $(document).find('.gldbm-panel').addClass('visible');
   });
});
```

AND

```
$('.menu-item-473').click( function() {
    $("#gldbm-panel").toggleClass("active");
} );
```

AND

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-item-473').click(function(){
         jQuery('#gldbm-panel').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

AND

```
$("#menu-item-473").click(function(){
  $("#gldbm-panel).addClass("active")
})
```

Comment: You're confusing ID selector syntax (`#`) and class selector syntax (`.`). The first example works fine otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/0amwpvdf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **'div'** correct id to bind the event. You have used classname with #. either use '.className' or '#id'.
On most of your trial, you have syntax error.

```js
 $("#wp_nav_menu-item-473").on('click',function(){
      $('#gldbm-panel').addClass('visible');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="menu-item-473" id="wp_nav_menu-item-473">hello</li>
</ul>
<div id="gldbm-panel" class="gldbm-panel">
```

Comment: check now, I have replace class name with id, i hope you have unique id in your code

Comment: Was a conflict in the end. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

A simple JS solution, get both elements correct by id or class ( i used querySelector for the class, preference) but it's up to you. Then wrap a simple toggle function via event listener for whenever you click in the li tag.

```
function toggleClass() {
  if (divElement.classList.contains('active')) divElement.classList.remove('active')
  else divElement.classList.add('active')
}

let liElement = document.querySelector('.menu-item-473')
let divElement = document.querySelector('.gldbm-panel')

liElement.addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
```

Comment: @AndySleat check [the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/r0uwa682/), the code works for a single div, if you have others with same class names you need to work with ID or a more general use case.

Comment: Was a conflict in the end. Thanks for your help though!